# Pandas delete rows with values same as column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows, where `Name, Marks, Grade` are the column names:

```
print (df)
    Name  Marks  Grade
0    Abc     70      A
1    Def     42      D
2    Ghi     54      D
3   Name  Marks  Grade
4    Jkl     31      F
5    Mno     76      B
6   Name  Marks  Grade
7    Pqr     B1      A
8    Stu     23      F
9    Vwx     90      A
10  Name  Marks  Grade
11    Yz     58      C
```

I wish to delete all those rows whose values are same as the column names so as to get the following dataframe -

```
print (df)
   Name Marks Grade
0   Abc    70     A
1   Def    42     D
2   Ghi    54     D
4   Jkl    31     F
5   Mno    76     B
7   Pqr    B1     A
8   Stu    23     F
9   Vwx    90     A
11   Yz    58     C
```

Can anybody suggest how this can be done?

Comment: How did the header rows (column name rows) get into the dataframe in the first place? Let's fix your CSV import/ Excel import. Anyway, we need you to post your actual dataframe, not just a screenshot.

Comment: If you know for example that in the third column 'Grade' is not a real grade, but the word itself that should be filtered, just do: `df = df[df['Grade'] != 'Grade']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare one column name, e.g. third and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
c = df.columns[2]

df1 = df[df[c] != c]
```

What working same like:

```
df1 = df[df['Grade'] != 'Grade']
```

If want compare all columns names it is possible too, only test if all values are `True`s per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df1 = df[(df != df.columns).all(axis=1)]
print (df1)
   Name Marks Grade
0   Abc    70     A
1   Def    42     D
2   Ghi    54     D
4   Jkl    31     F
5   Mno    76     B
7   Pqr    B1     A
8   Stu    23     F
9   Vwx    90     A
11   Yz    58     C
```

Comment: df1 = df[(df != df.columns).all(axis=1)] this approach solved my problem! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can drop rows that have for example have 'Marks' value in 'Marks' column using boolean mask and df.drop.

```py
bool_mask = df['Marks'] != 'Marks' #Make boolean mask where rows with 'Marks' are False.
df = df.drop(bool_mask)
```